# Having trouble merging cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm writing some VBA code that goes through my document and looks for where a formula returns an error and it merges and centers it with the cell that's underneath it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
     Dim strTemp As String
     Dim ev As Variant
     Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
     Set rng = Range("H87:H89")


For Each cell In rng
    If (cell.HasFormula) Then
        cell.Select

        strTemp = ActiveCell.Formula
        ev = Evaluate(strTemp)

        If (IsError(ev)) Then
            ActiveCell.Clear
            ActiveCell.Merge ([0,1])

        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, it clears the cell properly but won't merge.

Comment: No need to select/activate: e.g. `strTemp = cell.Formula`, `cell.Clear`, `cell.resize(2,1).merge`

Comment: Use VBA to select the active cell and the neighboring cell you want to merge with.  Then the code is Selection.MergeCells = True.

Comment: @TimWilliams Everything seems to be working fine until i get to the cell.Resize([2,1]).Merge line where I get a Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column)).Merge
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  Note you rarely need select/activate and should try to avoid it as much as possible.

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("H87:H89").Cells
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            If IsError(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Clear
                cell.Resize(2, 1).Merge
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```